# Select K unique random numbers from range with sum equal to S

Tags: algorithm, random

i have a range

```
R = {0, ..., N}
```

and i like to get `K` elements which have a sum equal to `S`, but the elements should be selected randomly.

So an easy brute force method would be to determine all element combinations containing `K` numbers resulting in `S` and picking one of the combinations by random.

I am trying to think about a recursive solution where a random number is selected and then the problem reduces to find (K-1) random numbers with sum equal to (S - K0) but this need not yield in a solution.

Is there a better approach?

A sample would be:

```
R = {0,1,2,3,4,5}, S = 5, K = 2
Solutions: randomly pick one of {{1,4};{2,3};{0.5}}
```

Comment: Can a given number from the input set be used more than once?

Comment: Is solution {0, 5} correct in the case of your example?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski yes it is correct, missed it

Comment: @MichałKomorowski: no the numbers have to be unique

Answer (score 1):

**In general, if K is big (then N also), and S not too little, it is unpredictable, because, there are two many combinations.**

Brute force: try every combinations. You are sure to find a solution, if there exists one, but if there are more than, say, 1 Md, or somewhat, it it almost impossible to list them all.

**Your algorithm:**

To choose at random, your algorithm is ok: take one number at random, then another, ...

But you make an assumption: there exists a solution with the numbers you pick: you dont know.

So what ? if statistically there exist many solutions, you could find it like that, *perhaps*, or *perhaps not*.

**Some trails:**

**1 Use S/K**

If every numbers < S/K, it is impossible.

if every numbers > S/K, it is impossible.

**So lets assume that there are numbers < S/K, and other > S/K**

2 keep only numbers < S, very interesting if S is little.

3 idea: If S is big, and numbers little, you have chance that there exist many combinations.

**idea of algorithm**

1 take one number N1 at random

2 if N1 < S/K, take another one N2 > S/K

3 calculate N1+N2: if < 2.S/K take another one N3> S/K, if not

4 iterate at each step: if sum < n S/K take another one > S/K, if not

5 you can have better precision, by replacing S/K by (S-sum N1,N2,...)/(K-n)

If at one step you dont can not find any number, backtrack

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would start with Dirichlet distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). Using it, you could sample uniformly in (0..1) distributed random numbers X<sub>i</sub>, such that Sum<sub>i</sub>X<sub>i</sub> = 1.

For `S <= N`, it is easy to see that sampling beyond `S` is useless and should be rejected outright.

So, combining with acceptance/rejection, something along the lines

- Divide interval [0...1] into `S` (or `S+1` if 0 is allowed) equal bins.
- Sample `K` numbers from Dirichlet distribution.
- Map sampled numbers to bin index, so you have now sampled integers which are
  all below or equal `S` and have sum equal to `S`.
- If all integers are distinct, accept the sampling, otherwise reject the sampling and go to step 2